# Deleting Particular Folder on Hard Disk Drive

Tags: hard-drive

My old laptop crashed, so I used the hard disk as a portable disk drive. I want to delete the windows folder on the disk drive and also consolidate the partitions into one single partition. Every time I try to delete the Program Files folder or the Windows folder I get an access denied message. Is there a way I can achieve deletion and consolidation?

Comment: You need to take ownership of the files/directories on the hard drive. See my answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You have all data you need of that HD?

You could use the drive management in the computer management to delete all partitions of that HD and create a new one.

Just be sure that you have EVERYTHING you need backuped of that HD. This process will delete everything and would be painful to restore.